# Multiple ngb-timepicker in one form with Angular4

Tags: angular, timepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular 4 to create a form with start time and end time, using two ngb-timepicker. When I set the model to both of them, the first one instantiates the values for the second one. Any idea on how to instantiate them separately?
My HTML looks like this:

```
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time1"></ngb-timepicker>
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time2"></ngb-timepicker>
```

And my component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'schedule-form',
 templateUrl: './schedule-form.component.html'
})

export class NgbdTimepickerBasic {
  time1 = {hour: startDateH, minute: startDateM};
  time2 = {hour: endDateH, minute: endDateM};
}
```

The result is that time1 will show time2, so only time2 is correct.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your issue is. Can you post a stackblitz that shows your issue?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/SVkL4mnrzkhHHP6NkDjL?p=preview  I was also using form control and because I could only use "ctrl" for both of them, it was instantiating both of them the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `NgbTimeStruct` to format the date which `ngb-timepicker` knows

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbTimeStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
 selector: 'schedule-form',
 templateUrl: './schedule-form.component.html'
})

export class NgbdTimepickerBasic {
  //declaration
  time1: NgbTimeStruct;
  time2: NgbTimeStruct;

  ngOnInit() {
    //get your start and end time and assign it to below 
    this.time1 = {hour: 13, minute: 30, second: 0};
    this.time2 = {hour: 16, minute: 15, second: 0};
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't declaring it as NgbTimeStruct