# ngb timepicker with [{ngModel}] inside a ngFor loop updating all the inputs of timepicker as all the timepickers have same ngmodel binding

Tags: angular, timepicker, ngmodel

I am using ngb timepicker inside a ngFor loop.

The timepicker html is as follows

```
<tr class="d-flex" *ngFor="let ct of workingTimingList.controls; let i = index; [formGroup]="ct" [attr.id]="'tr'+i">

<td>

<ngb-timepicker [attr.id]="'time'+i"  [attr.name]="'time'+i" [(ngModel)]="time"   formControlName="startTime"  #stTime [meridian]="meridian"  (click)="convertTiming(time.hour,time.minute, i, 'stTime', $event)"></ngb-timepicker>



</td>

</tr>
```

My .ts file is as follows

```
export class WorkingScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

time : any;

ngOnChanges() {
this.time = {hour:0 , minute:0};
}

}
```

Now if the loop has more than one row multiple ngb-timepicker is geting created with the same [(ngModel)]="time" and if I update one timepicker all the timepickers with [(ngModel)]="time" is getting updated.

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870514/multiple-ngb-timepicker-in-one-form-with-angular4

Comment: Not working in my case.

Comment: Solved the issue                                                                                           
          <ngb-timepicker [attr.id]="'time'+i"  [attr.name]="'time'+i" [(ngModel)]="time[i]"   formControlName="startTime"  #stTime [meridian]="meridian"  (click)="convertTiming(time[i].hour,time[i].minute, i, 'stTime', $event)"></ngb-timepicker>

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was to have multiple ngModels (one for each timepicker) you could go for an array of times: `times: any[]`

Then your html would look like this:

```
<tr class="d-flex" *ngFor="let ct of workingTimingList.controls; let i = index; [formGroup]="ct" [attr.id]="'tr'+i">
   <td>
   <ngb-timepicker [attr.id]="'time'+i"  [attr.name]="'time'+i" [(ngModel)]="times[i]"   
   formControlName="startTime"  #stTime [meridian]="meridian"  
   (click)="convertTiming(time.hour,time.minute, i, 'stTime', $event)"></ngb-timepicker>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Exactly that way I solved the issue two days before.